# In gerrit, how to clone project from HEAD:refs/for/master

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I try to use gerrit to do some test.
Use "git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master", 
before gerrit code review, I want to do some test by Jenkins.
How to use command to clone the commit from "refs/for/master"?
or fetch to Jenkins job workspace in order to test?

There is only one branch.

"git branch" -> *master

Answer (score 1):

When someone push a commit to review on Gerrit, the commit stays on the "magical" refs/for branch until it's finally submitted (merged). To have the commit locally you need to execute one of the download commands:

Checkout:

```
git fetch "https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/REPO-PATH" refs/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

Cherry Pick:

```
git fetch "https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/REPO-PATH" refs/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

Format Patch:

```
git fetch "https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/REPO-PATH" refs/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER && git format-patch -1 --stdout FETCH_HEAD
```

Pull:

```
git pull "https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/REPO-PATH" refs/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER
```

On Gerrit 3.0, you you'll find these commands at the change screen, clicking on the 3 dots at the up-right and then in the "Download patch" option.

See more info at the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-review-ui.html#download).

Using Jenkins, you can execute some of these commands too, but it's easier to use the [Gerrit Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger).